# Save Excel file to Windows via Weblogic Server?

Tags: excel, maven, servlets, weblogic, apache-poi

I have created a Maven project and written a Servlet which uses the Apache POI to save an excel spreadsheet. When I deploy the project as a WAR onto a Weblogic Server and run it. It doesn't save the excel sheet to the windows location specified. How can I save the excel sheet to a windows location from Weblogic server?

```
public class excelGenerator extends HttpServlet{

 /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);

    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");

                // Create a new row in current sheet
                Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
                // //Create a new cell in current row
                Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                // //Set value to new value
                cell.setCellValue("Blahblah");

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\work\\excel.xls"));
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");
    }

}
```

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue? i.e. are you sure that whatever account weblog runs as has write permissions to that folder?

Comment: There shouldn't be a permissions issue. I can write a file to the server itself but not outside the server?

Comment: "C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\" Are you trying to save on the client?  Because you can only save on the server.  You'd have to serve the Excel to the client over the web and let them save wherever they want.